# fidiv: improper operand type error when dividing by register

Tags: assembly, x86, fpu

Take the following piece of code:

```
void calculate(int int_number) {
    __asm {
        fld1
        mov eax, 5
        fidiv eax    ; A
    }
}
```

If I try to to compile it, the A line fails with `error C2415: improper operand type`. The same problem happens if I replace `eax` with integer constant. However, if I pass `int_number` as a `fidiv` parameter:

```
void calculate(int int_number) {
    __asm {
        fld1
        fidiv int_number
    }
}
```

the code compiles properly.

So what’s wrong with dividing by a register?

I’m using Visual Studio on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: The machine instruction `fidiv` cannot be applied to a register; it must load the operand from memory by the use of indirect addressing. The only argument must have the form `dword ptr CONSTANT[REGISTER]`. When you write `fidiv <local_variable_or_function_argument>` the compiler replaces it with `fidiv dword ptr OFFSET[ebp]` according to the layout of the stack frame for your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the answer already being the comments: the operand must be a memory operand.

Look in the manual, it says:

> DA /6 FIDIV m32int
>   DE /6 FIDIV m16int

It does not list `FIDIV r/m32int` which it would have if you could choose a register for that operand as well. Some groups of FPU instructions (groups based on their first byte) are split in two subgroups that have different instructions in them (all groups are split, but some, like `D8`, are split in two subgroups that only differ by their operands). The `DA` and `DE` groups are examples of groups that are split into two radically different subgroups. The groups are split based on the "mod" field in the ModR/M byte, with 00 though 10 being one group, and 11 being the other group.

In the groups where the second group is "normal", a mod field of 11 indicates the use of ST(i) operands. In the "weird" groups, it makes the instruction mean something entirely different.

For example `DA F0`, that you might have wanted to mean `FIDIV eax`, actually means .. nothing. There's a hole in the table there. `DA C0` on the other hand, that you might have wanted to mean
`FIADD eax`, actually means `FCMOVB st(0), st(0)`.